# how to list all pairs of sexy primes

Tags: c, primes

How can i write a program that lists all sexy prime pairs that exist in n numbers.
For example if n = 10 the output should be (5, 11) and (7, 13)

My idea was to generate all primes within n and then add 6 to each and  check if the i + 6 is a prime. But it doesnt work, there's no output and the program ends.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i, j, n, k, isprime = 1, prime2, flag = 0;
  
    scanf("%d", &n);
          
    for (i = 3; i <= n; i++){
      for (j = 2; j <= i; j++){
        if (i % j == 0)
          break;
      }

      if (i == j){
        prime2 = i + 6;
        for (k = 3; k <= prime2; k++){
          if (prime2 % k == 0){
            flag++;
            break;
          }
        }

        if (flag == 0){
          printf("%d %d\n", i, prime2);
        }     
      }
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Any ideas of what im doing wrong or any tips on how to solve it? (with loops only)

Comment: *it doesn't work* isn't a meaningful problem description. You should [edit] your post to make it more clear what the problem is with the code you've posted, and to ask a specific question about that code.

Comment: I suggest you write a separate `is_prime()` function. Then you can simply test `if (is_prime(i) && is_prime(i+6))`

Comment: You need to reset `flag` within the outer loop. -- It's more efficient to save the previous prime and see if it was 6 behind the current one.

Comment: @KenWhite edited it

Comment: @Barmar i can't use functions, its kind of a homework so i can only use loops

Comment: @500-InternalServerError it still has no output. Do I need to use vectors to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there're a lot of resources about finding a prime number, I'm not going to discuss that. Rather I'll try to point out the bug in your code.

**First problem:**

```
for (k = 3; k <= prime2; k++)
```

Here you need to run the loop till `prime2 - 1`. Also you should start checking from `2` rather than `3`, just like you did previously. That means,

```
for (k = 2; k < prime2; k++)
```

or

```
for (k = 2; k <= prime2 - 1; k++)
```

**Reason:** when `k = prime2`, `prime2 % k` will be `0`. For finding out whether a number is prime we don't need to check if that number is divisible by `1` and that number itself.

Note: Now you might think why the first prime number loop for `(j = 2; j <= i; j++)` is working .

It's working because you've given an additional condition `if (i == j)` after it.

**Second problem:**

You need to declare the `flag` variable within the first loop.

```
for (i = 2; i <= n; i++)
{
    int flag = 0;
    .... (rest of the code)
    ....
}
```

**Reason:** Basically with the `flag` value, you're trying to find out whether `prime2` is a prime number.

Every time you'll get a prime number from the first loop, you'll have a new value of `prime2`. In your code, once you're incrementing the value of `flag`, you're never resetting the `flag` value.

That's why once your code detects a `prime2` which is not a prime, it'll never detect the second prime number again (`prime2` which is actually prime).

Overall code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j, n, k, isprime = 1, prime2;

    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i = 3; i <= n; i++)
    {
        int flag = 0;    //  changing point
        for (j = 2; j <= i; j++)
        {
            if (i % j == 0)
                break;
        }

        if (i == j)
        {
            prime2 = i + 6;

            for (k = 2; k < prime2; k++)    //  changing point
            {
                if (prime2 % k == 0)
                {
                    flag++;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (flag == 0)
            {
                printf("%d %d\n", i, prime2);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Few resources to know more about finding out prime numbers:

- [Prime Numbers](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/prime-numbers/)
- [C Program to Check Whether a Number is Prime or not](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-program-to-check-whether-a-number-is-prime-or-not/)
- [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sieve-of-eratosthenes/)

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation! Its perfectly working now

Comment: You're always welcome. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sieve to speed up the program. It can generate all pairs in O(N log N) time. Here's the [Algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sieve-of-eratosthenes/).

Now, you have a boolean array, `is_prime` where `is_prime[i]` is true if `i` is a prime, false otherwise.

Now, iterate from `i = 1` to `i = N` and check if `is_prime[i] && is_prime[i + 6]`, if the condition is true, output the pair.